# How does Binance Smart Chain and Pancake swap handle transactions?

Tags: binance

I am trying to create a coin similar to Safemoon with an added type of reflection, but my friend claims that because I am adding another for loop that the gas fees will be too high.

Do high computationally taxing transactions result in more fees?

I know a little about Big O notation but I am not an expert. Can somebody elaborate on how Pancake / BSC determines how much to charge based on each transaction's computational needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> *Do high computationally taxing transactions result in more fees?*

Mostly yes. For loops produce a linear complexity.

Each storage write costs 5,000 gas, which is one of the most expensive smart contract instructions. So if your function is executable (not `view` or `pure`) and has a loop with 10 iterations, each containing one storage write, that's going to cost the user a total of 71,000 gas (21k base fee + 10 * 5k).

> *Can somebody elaborate on how Pancake / BSC determines how much to charge*

The transaction fee is not calculated by the exchange. It's your wallet that calculates it based on the set of instructions (memory read, storage write, etc; determinable from the contract bytecode and your transaction data) and the gas price of each instruction (hardcoded in the network).